# Creating a monad for repeating methods

Tags: scala, monads

I'm trying to understand what monads are in Scala.

Say for example I have methods in Java like this:

```
public void doSomeThing()
{
   a.call();
}

public void doOtherThing()
{
   a2.call();
}

public void doSomeOtherThing()
{
   a3.call();
}
```

All the methods that starts with `do`, just only do the method call named `call`. If I convert that into a common method in Java like:

```
public void doGeneric(SomeClass a)
{
   a.call();
}
```

and say this as a generic method, with does the `call` function, then `doGeneric` is an monad? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Note that I gave the examples in Java, as I'm just now starting with Scala.

Comment: What made you think it is? Were you thinking of the function monad?

Comment: No I'm asking in general, my idea fits into what in FP called `monad`

Answer (score 1):

Monad is associated to the notion of "container" like `Option` or `List`.
Basically, a container that defines the `flatMap` method is a monad:

```
trait Monad[A] { //let's say a Monad container to be general. A well-known would be Option
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Monad[B]): Monad[B]
}
```

In your case, you simply call a method on one object.
You are not computing a "container"'s value from another container, so you haven't got a monad.
Indeed, you just make use of polymorphism.

Comment: So your saying will define monad and have the default implentation works for any types. Right?

Comment: You should look at the course on coursera.org called "Reactive programming", there's a great chapter on the monad in video by Martin Odersky.